# New Linux Azure VM not accessible after reboot from portal (deallocation)

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

We recently created a new Azure Virtual Network (Regional) to support internal load balancing, among other things.
We migrated the Windows Server 2012 R2 VMs from the old VNET to the new VNET without issue.
The Linux VMs did not migrate.  I attempted to recreate the VMs using an image that I took from the configured linux VM on the old VNET.  This image was confirmed to work for deployment as I deployed 5 different instances using that same image.
I attempted to deploy the VM to the new VNET and deployment succeeded.  After a full shutdown from the azure portal (deallocating the resources from the VM), and starting it up again, I am unable to connect to the VM remotely (over the public endpoint and the private network), nor PING over the private network.

I then decided to start from scratch with a new Linux Image (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), and created a new cloud service on the new VNET for that image.  Deployment again succeeded and connectivity was solid until shutting it down (deallocating) and rebooting it up again.

It seems as though deallocating the resources on Linux VMs is causing some problems on Regional Virtual Networks.

Does anyone have a solution for how to go about deploying linux and maintaining functionality after a full reboot/deallocation?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a Regional Private Network using Location instead of Affinity Group: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157100.aspx
2. Create a new Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM on the virtual network from the Azure VM Gallery (Using the Portal)
3. After the VM is up, test connectivity (Success)
4. Shut down the VM from the Azure Management Portal
5. Start the VM again from the Azure Management Portal
6. Test Connectivity (Fail)

**EDIT 5/29/2014**

I just got the same exact connectivity failure with a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM.
No Connectivity after deallocating the VM and then starting it again.

**EDIT 5/30/2014**

Looks like it has gotten worse.  Deallocation no longer required for connectivity loss. I deployed both a new Ubuntu 14.04 image from the Azure Gallery as well as a new Windows 2012 R2 image from the Azure Gallery and was unable to connect to either *immediately* after deployment.

Also, Confirmed that this is directly related to deploying it on the virtual network.  If I deploy the same image to East US and no VNET assigned, I can access it without issue across the public endpoint.

Comment: I havent brought up an Ubuntu VM for a while, but there is no reason to expect that it cant survive a deallocation.  It should just come right back.  Are you doing anything special with it? what are you doing to test connectivity?

Comment: See steps to reproduce. Not doing anything special... Literally created a brand new VM from scratch (the image gallery) and tested connectivity to it by SSH and PING over public and private IP.  Shut down the VM from the portal and then brought it back up. After that, I can no longer connect to it.  Also, deploying from the image hangs at "Installing extensions in virtual machine xxx..." - To clarify, deploying from the image I create is a separate process than the one described above.  Both deploying from the Azure Gallery Image and the Image I took before fail after deallocation.

Comment: I just deployed a Ubuntu VM into a regional network and observed the same loss of external and internal connectivity following a shutdown/deallocation and restart.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  I also tested deploying via Powershell and lost connectivity after moving the VM to a subnet.

Comment: There is a "Reset Password" option worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug and working with MS support, they now have it fixed.  No issues with new linux vms anymore.

Comment: What about existing linux vms with this issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: @dcinzona, i am getting similar error after taking the vm image capture operation. the error i am getting is, "Operation 'restart' is not allowed on VM 'XXXXX' since the VM is generalized." Do u have any fix?

Comment: @Suriya Did you figure this problem out?  I have the exact same issue.